# Alternative for ANY keyword in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to execute query in SQLite, but as SQLite does not support ANY keyword, is there any alternative query which will produce the same result.

Below is the query which I want to execute in SQLite:

```
select * from ORDERsy 
where amount < any(select amount from ORDERsy where odate = '06-oct-1999');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MAX`:

```
select * 
from ORDERsy 
where amount < (select MAX(amount) from ORDERsy where odate = '06-oct-1999');
```

> From [ALL, ANY and SOME Comparison Conditions in SQL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql):
>
> **"x < ANY (...)": The value must be smaller than the biggest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE.**

Answer (score 0):

use **exists** is another solution, and it can support more scenarios, like **sub string match**, **between one range** etc.

```
select * from ORDERsy or1
where exists (select 1 from ORDERsy or2 where odate = '06-oct-1999' and or1.amount<or2.amount);
```